# Disabling entire slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

How can I disable/enable the entire grid ? (greying out and disabling mouse and keyboard)

I tried wrapping the grid div in a fieldset and then doing:

```
$(grid.getContainerNode()).parent().prop('disabled', true);
```

I can see the fieldset gets the disabled property but the grid still respond to mouse/scroll etc

Any help ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to do and I don' understand why you would want to do that either. I would assume that all the subscriptions that were created internally still remain in place and you don't have to access to these subscriptions (unless you destroy the grid), you only have access to subscriptions you create yourself. You can disable editing but not really the entire grid.

Comment: the idea is that while ie an ajax call is going on the user should not be able to scroll the grid/resize columns/edit cells etc

Comment: Personally, I'd just add a css style to the page making it look like the grid is disabled and use the ```editable``` option to prevent editing. eg. ```.slickgrid_360183 .slick-cell { background-color: lightgray; }```

Comment: Any idea why the fieldset trick above doesn't work ?